# Public testing environment for RoR + Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, testing, build, project-management

currently I need a little hint for test running a RoR + Angular Application. And with test running I talk about that the "project owner" can see the current version of the project. For large projects with a lot of developers we had a build server, where the server got the current version from the git repository and deployed it as a "nightly build".

For projects where I'm the only developer I use dropbox to synchronize my working directory to a server, that is accessible for the project owner.

But now I'm working on a small project with 2 other developers. The build server is too much and the dropbox solution, well it's not going to work, because every one of us has a different state. And working on the same Dropbox directory is a no go.

So what's the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Consider running it on [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com), which has a free tier. Once set up properly, deployments can be done by simply pushing to your Heroku git remote, or you can set it up to watch an existing remote repository branch (such as a particular branch on Github).

Or you could run it on your own machine. If you are behind a firewall you could set up a tunnel so your team can see it, with something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).